# How to "install" LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, cli, install

I need to start with LWC but I used my company pc, and it has some bureaucracies to install software so I cannot install Salesforce CLI.. There's another way? Extension on Visual Studio Code works?

Comment: Even the VSCode extension has a dependency on the Salesforce CLI, FYI. You will need to follow the steps in this Trail: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/set-up-your-lightning-web-components-developer-tools

Answer (score 4):

If you already have NodeJS installed, you can install the CLI with Node Package Manager:

```
npm install -g sfdx-cli
```

This will give access to all of the sfdx commands without a binary install, and without any need for elevated Administrator permissions.

Comment: https://www.vermanshul.com/2019/11/quick-tips-setup-sfdx-manually-without.html

Comment: in case you don't have node installed, as it could require admin as well